# How can I display a diagonal line with a rainbow gradient in a 16-bit assembly simulator whose colours (in the source code) are in hexadecimal?

Tags: assembly, colors, rgb, 16-bit

I'm trying to **programmatically** display a line in a 16-bit assembly simulator with a **rainbow gradient** like in this picture:

[image: Rainbow gradient I'm trying to achieve]

The online simulator I'm using is [this one](https://parraman.github.io/asm-simulator) and you can find the source code [over here](https://github.com/parraman/asm-simulator).

As we can see in the source code the colour palette is the following one:

```
const COLOR_PALETTE = [

    '#000000', '#000055', '#0000AA', '#0000FF', '#002400', '#002455', '#0024AA', '#0024FF', /* 0x00..0x07 */
    '#004800', '#004855', '#0048AA', '#0048FF', '#006C00', '#006C55', '#006CAA', '#006CFF', /* 0x08..0x0F */
    '#009000', '#009055', '#0090AA', '#0090FF', '#00B400', '#00B455', '#00B4AA', '#00B4FF', /* 0x10..0x17 */
    '#00D800', '#00D855', '#00D8AA', '#00D8FF', '#00FC00', '#00FC55', '#00FCAA', '#00FCFF', /* 0x18..0x1F */
    '#240000', '#240055', '#2400AA', '#2400FF', '#242400', '#242455', '#2424AA', '#2424FF', /* 0x20..0x27 */
    '#244800', '#244855', '#2448AA', '#2448FF', '#246C00', '#246C55', '#246CAA', '#246CFF', /* 0x28..0x2F */
    '#249000', '#249055', '#2490AA', '#2490FF', '#24B400', '#24B455', '#24B4AA', '#24B4FF', /* 0x30..0x37 */
    '#24D800', '#24D855', '#24D8AA', '#24D8FF', '#24FC00', '#24FC55', '#24FCAA', '#24FCFF', /* 0x38..0x3F */
    '#480000', '#480055', '#4800AA', '#4800FF', '#482400', '#482455', '#4824AA', '#4824FF', /* 0x40..0x47 */
    '#484800', '#484855', '#4848AA', '#4848FF', '#486C00', '#486C55', '#486CAA', '#486CFF', /* 0x48..0x4F */
    '#489000', '#489055', '#4890AA', '#4890FF', '#48B400', '#48B455', '#48B4AA', '#48B4FF', /* 0x50..0x57 */
    '#48D800', '#48D855', '#48D8AA', '#48D8FF', '#48FC00', '#48FC55', '#48FCAA', '#48FCFF', /* 0x58..0x5F */
    '#6C0000', '#6C0055', '#6C00AA', '#6C00FF', '#6C2400', '#6C2455', '#6C24AA', '#6C24FF', /* 0x60..0x67 */
    '#6C4800', '#6C4855', '#6C48AA', '#6C48FF', '#6C6C00', '#6C6C55', '#6C6CAA', '#6C6CFF', /* 0x68..0x6F */
    '#6C9000', '#6C9055', '#6C90AA', '#6C90FF', '#6CB400', '#6CB455', '#6CB4AA', '#6CB4FF', /* 0x70..0x77 */
    '#6CD800', '#6CD855', '#6CD8AA', '#6CD8FF', '#6CFC00', '#6CFC55', '#6CFCAA', '#6CFCFF', /* 0x78..0x7F */
    '#900000', '#900055', '#9000AA', '#9000FF', '#902400', '#902455', '#9024AA', '#9024FF', /* 0x80..0x87 */
    '#904800', '#904855', '#9048AA', '#9048FF', '#906C00', '#906C55', '#906CAA', '#906CFF', /* 0x88..0x8F */
    '#909000', '#909055', '#9090AA', '#9090FF', '#90B400', '#90B455', '#90B4AA', '#90B4FF', /* 0x90..0x97 */
    '#90D800', '#90D855', '#90D8AA', '#90D8FF', '#90FC00', '#90FC55', '#90FCAA', '#90FCFF', /* 0x98..0x9F */
    '#B40000', '#B40055', '#B400AA', '#B400FF', '#B42400', '#B42455', '#B424AA', '#B424FF', /* 0xA0..0xA7 */
    '#B44800', '#B44855', '#B448AA', '#B448FF', '#B46C00', '#B46C55', '#B46CAA', '#B46CFF', /* 0xA8..0xAF */
    '#B49000', '#B49055', '#B490AA', '#B490FF', '#B4B400', '#B4B455', '#B4B4AA', '#B4B4FF', /* 0xB0..0xB7 */
    '#B4D800', '#B4D855', '#B4D8AA', '#B4D8FF', '#B4FC00', '#B4FC55', '#B4FCAA', '#B4FCFF', /* 0xB8..0xBF */
    '#D80000', '#D80055', '#D800AA', '#D800FF', '#D82400', '#D82455', '#D824AA', '#D824FF', /* 0xC0..0xC7 */
    '#D84800', '#D84855', '#D848AA', '#D848FF', '#D86C00', '#D86C55', '#D86CAA', '#D86CFF', /* 0xC8..0xCF */
    '#D89000', '#D89055', '#D890AA', '#D890FF', '#D8B400', '#D8B455', '#D8B4AA', '#D8B4FF', /* 0xD0..0xD7 */
    '#D8D800', '#D8D855', '#D8D8AA', '#D8D8FF', '#D8FC00', '#D8FC55', '#D8FCAA', '#D8FCFF', /* 0xD8..0xDF */
    '#FC0000', '#FC0055', '#FC00AA', '#FC00FF', '#FC2400', '#FC2455', '#FC24AA', '#FC24FF', /* 0xE0..0xE7 */
    '#FC4800', '#FC4855', '#FC48AA', '#FC48FF', '#FC6C00', '#FC6C55', '#FC6CAA', '#FC6CFF', /* 0xE8..0xEF */
    '#FC9000', '#FC9055', '#FC90AA', '#FC90FF', '#FCB400', '#FCB455', '#FCB4AA', '#FCB4FF', /* 0xF0..0xF7 */
    '#FCD800', '#FCD855', '#FCD8AA', '#FCD8FF', '#FCFC00', '#FCFC55', '#FCFCAA', '#FFFFFF', /* 0xF8..0xFF */

];
```

And, as we can see annotated on it's side, we can access to those colours using a specific number (the array position). For example, we use '0' for defining black as it's the first colour in the array. Using Python I got an image showing me the colour organization of that array.

[image: visual representation of the colour palette]

This is my take on colouring the diagonal but I want it to have a rainbow gradient:

```
colourDisplay EQU 0x300       ; Adress value for the visual display memory cell

boot:
    MOV D, colourDisplay      ; Point register D to display output
    MOV C, 16                 ; Point register C to value 16
    MOVB BL, 8                
    JMP print                 ; Bring us to the print function

print:
    MOVB [D], BL              ; Sets the colour into the display
    ADD D, 17                 ; We point to the next display cell in order to paint the next colours
    INCB BL
    DEC C                     ; C = C - 1
    JNZ print                 ; If we havent reach 0 in the counter (C) we jump to the beginning
    HLT                       ; Halt execution
```

That code displays this **unwanted** gradient:

[image: bad gradient]

It doesn't really matter if it's a diagonal or any other shape, I just want to achieve this reordering of the colour palette without modifying the source code.

Comment: Since this is indexed colours, the easiest way is to manually pick out the colour indexes you want to use in the gradient (0xE0, 0xF0, 0xF8, ...). There are mathematical ways that could look at the RGB values and pick out the proper indexes to use, but that requires mapping arbitrary 24-bit RGB values to the closest value available in your palette.

Comment: The problem I have is that I dont want to pick the colors manually. How would you do that mapping? @1201ProgramAlarm